# Global.asax Application_Start not hit after upgrade to Sitecore 8.2

Tags: application

We noticed the `Application_Start` in the `Global asax` is no longer hit after the upgrade to `Sitecore 8.2`.

Does anyone have an idea what may have caused this?

**My global.asax.cs:**

```cs
public class Global : Sitecore.Web.Application
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

**Global.asax:**

```cs
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="[namespace].Global" Language="C#" %>
```

**Edit:**

In order to be sure the Application_Start is not hit I did a few tests:

- Added a System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
- Edited the Global.asax file while the debugger was attached
- Threw an exception

None of the above were successful.

The target `framework is set to 4.6`

Comment: Are you sure it's not hit? Can easily go wrong, if you're relying on attaching a debugger to see a breakpoint get hit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967813/why-does-not-the-application-start-event-fire-when-i-debug-my-asp-net-mvc-app

Comment: Yes, I added a System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() which did not work. Then changed the global.asax while the debugger was attached and even threw an exception to make sure it's not hit.

Comment: Right. Hmm. And you've changed your build target to .NET 4.5.2?

Comment: The target framework is set to 4.6

Comment: @NicoGeeroms You're probably not restarting the app completely. Detach the debugger, then stop the application pool in IIS, then start it again. See if `Application_Start` is executed then. Don't use exceptions to check if it's executed (you won't necessarily see them and the app will start anyway). Instead, use `Debugger.Break()` or write to a file on disk, or something similar.

Comment: It's still not executed. I used the exception as a last resort after trying the Debugger.Break() etc.

Comment: Have you tried changing the target framework to 4.5.2, as per Mark's suggestion?

Comment: Just a thought, Hope you had published in debug mode not in release mode. :) or just get ready, update web.config or reset IIS, refresh the page and attach the worker process. It works actually. Also check Configuration and Platform in Configurations Manager that Configuration is Debug and Platform is Any CPU.

Comment: Yes, I did but that didn't work either.

Comment: The application is indeed published in debug mode, other breakpoints from the same assembly are hit.

I killed the worker process, added Debug.Launch/Break etc.. I'm sure it has nothing to do with the way I try to debug it. The problem is Application_Start is not hit at all.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is best practice to not modify the global.asax file. Best to use the Sitecore pipelines to accomplish the same task. This allows you to follow Helix more closely and makes upgrading the site simpler.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Sitecore.Pipelines;

namespace YourApp.Pipelines.Initialize
{
    public class RegisterApiRoutes : Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes
    {
        public override void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
           // app start here
        }
    }
}
```

Then your config

```
<pipelines>
  <initialize>
    <processor type="YourApp.Pipelines.Initialize.RegisterApiRoutes, YourApp" />
  </initialize>
</pipelines>
```

Other Global.asax functions https://laubplusco.net/global-asax-sitecore-pipelines/

Comment: How one should decide which to use between `Pipelines.Loader.InitializeAspNetMvc`, `Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory`, `Pipelines.Loader.InitializeDependencyResolver`, `Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters`, `Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes`? Which gets executed first?

Comment: You can see the order in /admin/showconfig.aspx. Look for the processors with the types you stated above. . Its InitializeAspNetMvc, InitializeGlobalFilters, InitializeDependencyResolver, InitializeControllerFactory and finally InitializeRoutes. Each processor assists in a different part of the MVC initialization.

Answer (score 28):

The `Application_Start` method of `Sitecore.Web.Application` has been made internal in 8.2 which is why you cannot override it and your method is not being hit.

```cs
internal void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ServiceLocator.MakeReadonly();
}
```

You will have to use the `initialize` pipeline as mentioned by [dnstommy](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2311/55), which is also best practice.

Comment: Sitecore Support confirmed that making Application_Start internal is a bug and has been registered with reference #126372.

Answer (score -2):

You may need to check if your Global asax inherits from Sitecore.Web.Application

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application" Language="C#" %>
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? Right now it doesn't really help with why this would fix the issue the question is asking. The answer should also contain some additional information that would make it stand out as a separate answer from the other answers (especially the one that was marked as the fix)