# How to ignore (and test) /sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx in MiniProfiler

Tags: performance-profiling

I'm using MiniProfiler in a Sitecore project. I've set up MiniProfiler to ignore a bunch of sitecore specific paths, including `/sitecore/`.

I left the page open for a while and after refreshing I see a bunch of entries on `/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx`:

[image: screenshot of miniprofiler showing /sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx entries]

How can I get MiniProfiler to ignore `/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx`?

How can I test that it's being ignored properly?

For reference, here's the relevant part of the `Global.asax.cs` file:

```cs
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitMiniProfilerSettings();
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MiniProfiler.Start();
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MiniProfiler.Stop();
}

private static void InitMiniProfilerSettings()
{
    MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths =
        MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths
            .Append(
                "WebResource.axd",
                "/Styles/",
                ".axd",
                ".xml",
                ".mp3",
                ".flv",
                ".js",
                ".css",
                ".gif",
                ".png",
                ".jpg",
                ".woff",
                ".ttf",
                "sc_mode=edit",
                "~/media",
                "-/media",
                "~/icon",
                "/sitecore/"
            )
            .ToArray();
}
```

<sub>`Append` is an extension method that concatenates the parameters on the provided enumerable.</sub>

Comment: For testing purposes, it appears that visiting `/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx` directly is sufficient.

Comment: Turns out this is a duplicate of http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/2305/286

Comment: Why do you think this is a duplicate of the other question? Your question is about ignoring `/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx` in MiniProfiler. The other one is about `Application_Start` not being hit. The root problem of these two questions may be the same, but the questions themselves are not the same.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko, the cause of the problem was exactly that `Application_Start` was never running, which is where my `IgnoredPaths` setting was supposed to be set. The fact that miniprofiler was failing was a red herring to the underlying issue that `Application_Start` was not running, and therefor "This question already has an answer" on the linked question as per the duplicate close reason. There is no answer that can be provided to this question that would not be better suited on the linked question.

Comment: Also note, I have *closed* the question as a duplicate, but that doesn't mean that it will necessarily be deleted. It may stick around as a funnel to point people to the right answer should they happen to have a similar issue.