# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator - Opening Content Editor

Tags: solr, indexing

I was trying to setup the Sitecore with Solr. I created the Default Instance and added Solr.

I use Castle Windsor as IOC, updated the Global.asax.

Since I was not able to download the Solr Support Package, I use the GIT source to compile and get the other needed dlls for solr.

https://github.com/Sitecore/Solr.SupportPackage

The configuration is done successfully. The solr is working fine.

In the Index Manager, Indexing is done. Now When try to browse the Content Editor I get the below error.

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator]
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrIndexParameters..ctor(IIndexValueFormatter valueFormatter, IFieldQueryTranslatorMap`1 fieldQueryTranslators, FieldNameTranslator fieldNameTranslator, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts, IFieldMapReaders fieldMap, Boolean convertQueryDatesToUtc) +315
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.LinqToSolrIndex`1..ctor(SolrSearchContext context, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts) +188
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchContext.GetQueryable(IExecutionContext[] executionContexts) +268
   Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.TestingSearch.GetAllTests() +195
   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.GetContentTestingWarnings.AddSuspendedTestWarning(GetContentEditorWarningsArgs args) +63
   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.GetContentTestingWarnings.Process(GetContentEditorWarningsArgs args) +43
   (Object , Object[] ) +71
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.GetWarnings(Boolean hasSections) +307
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.Render(RenderContentEditorArgs args, Control parent) +160
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.RenderEditor(Item item, Item root, Control editorsContainer, Boolean showEditor) +295
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateEditor(Item folder, Item root, Boolean showEditor) +488
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update() +568
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs e) +172

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +143
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +107
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7675
```

When I try to see the Experience Editor, it open succesfully but with similar error message on top.

```
An error occurred. [Log message: Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator]
```

I did try to see the other post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516859/getting-error-on-content-editor-after-upgrading-to-sitecore-8), but it was not helpful.

Not sure where things are going wrong, can someone throw some light ?

What does it mean Solr Index Parameters ?

**Finally Found Solution**

1. I haven't checked the Sitecore logs, it was emitting errors like 'Unable to connect to [http://localhost:8983/solr], Core: ...'
2. Overlooked the Index Manager, Rebuild Job Running Status. It has some errors.
3. Another major thing I missed was, haven't created all the core's required in Solr.

I hope this may help someone, who is starting Solr!

Comment: what IOC Container are you using ? Did you modify global.asax to use a container ?

Comment: I use Castle Castle Windsor for IOC, Solr.SupportPackage i downloaded from the GitHub, as updated in the question.

Comment: Do you have on global.asax <%@Application Language=’C#’ Inherits=”Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorApplication”%>” ?

Comment: Are you sure your global asax code is hit? See here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/global-asax-application-start-not-hit-after-upgrade-to-sitecore-8-2

Comment: _Since I was not able to download the Solr Support Package, I use the GIT source to compile and get the other needed dlls for solr._ - Can you explain more about your Sitecore instance and issue downloading the support package

Comment: I use developer license shared by company, so I don't have access to download the additional tools from the sitecore site directly. So I use the GIT Hub Source where .net source for Solr Support Package is available.

Comment: Just to add another option to try.

I had the same problem with Sitecore 8.2 Update-2 and to solve I switched to run with Castle, so I was able to rebuild my indexes. After that I switched back to the default implementation and it solved.

Comment: The first time I ran rebuild indexes it finished instantly. I had to run it again and then it actually started rebuilding them.

Answer (score 4):

Just Check your Solr Service is working fine.You can find the **"ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress"** in this 
**"App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config"** Config file.

If you are having multiple instance in your local then check the SOLR service running with correct path and your project indexes.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error with Sitecore 9 - in my case, it was due to a misconfiguration in the `sitecore/settings/setting[@name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress"]` value.

You can find where this is set in the `App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` configuration file. Check that this value points to the Solr instance you're using, and confirm that the protocol is the same. For us, an update had overridden the value we had from https to http which caused the errors.

Comment: Confirming that the protocol (http / https) is correct is the key.