# Requested document not found when using MVC routes

Tags: mvc, routing, custom-route

I am getting 404s (requested document not found) when I try to use a custom route I created per the guide here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/700677. My patch config is showing up in showconfig, here's what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="[obfuscated].Pipelines.Routes.RegisterCustomRoute, [obfuscated]" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The processor code:

namespace BrightHorizons.Pipelines.Routes

```
{
    public class RegisterCustomRoute
    {
        public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("CustomRoute", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}");
        }
    }
}
```

The controller action and controller name seem correct... here's what that looks like:

```
public class FindACenterController : GlassController
{
    public ActionResult FindACenterMap()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am trying to access it like this:
`http://mysite/api/FindACenter/FindACenterMap`

I also tried using a basic Default route in the RouteConfig.cs (`/{controller}/{action}/{id}`) under App_Start before that and it did not work either. I am really not good at MVC routing so looking for some guidance.

**UPDATE:** 
FindACenterMap is now working, however this is not working for a different controller. Added a new route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("SubmitScheduleVisit",
    "api/SubmitScheduleVisit",
    new { controller = "FindACenter", action = "SubmitScheduleVisit" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);
```

It's in the same controller. This is the action definition:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitScheduleVisit(string selectedDate, string selectedTime, string firstName, string lastName,
            string emailAddress, string phoneNumber, string whenToStart, List<string> childDatesOfBirth)
{
     ....
}
```

**SOLUTION TO UPDATE** (Not a solution to the original question): I simply had to run the query in Postman. I was testing the API call in Firefox which meant it was getting run as a GET, not a POST. Solved.

Comment: Apparently there is this thing called `Global.asax` that I need to run the RegisterRoutes()? I thought that was web forms only? I added that and call RegisterRoutes() and no difference

Comment: You do not need to modify the global.asax. Using the initialize pipeline replaces that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is code I reuse constantly. The only caveat is that is the controller is in a different project/library than the route initialization code, strange thing happen. I always keep the controller and initialize code together.

Your url would now be `http://mysite/api/FindACenterMap`

Please see this answer while modification of the global.asax is not required. [Global.asax Application_Start not hit after upgrade to Sitecore 8.2](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/global-asax-application-start-not-hit-after-upgrade-to-sitecore-8-2/2311#2311)

#### The route

```
public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("FindACenterMap",
        "api/FindACenterMap",
        new { controller = "FindACenter", action = "FindACenterMap" },
        new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
    );

    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("SubmitScheduleVisit",
        "api/SubmitScheduleVisit",
        new { controller = "FindACenter", action = "SubmitScheduleVisit" },
        new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
    );
}
```

#### The controller

```
public class FindACenterController : GlassController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FindACenterMap()
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitScheduleVisit(string selectedDate, string selectedTime, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string phoneNumber, string whenToStart, List<string> childDatesOfBirth)
    {
            ....
    }
 }
```

#### The config

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="[obfuscated].Pipelines.Routes.RegisterCustomRoute, [obfuscated]" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hmm, I am getting a yellow screen error here - `The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
Parameter name: routeUrl`, and it's pointing to the route in `RegisterCustomRoute.cs`. If I remove the leading `/` I get an IIS detailed 404 again.

Comment: Actually it *is* working for `FindACenterMap`. However when I use this for another controller action which is a POST (and I change the http method to POST) I am getting the IIS detailed 404. I have `[HttpPost]` above the controller definition.

Comment: Did you change the route to POST? like this, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") } with [HttpPost] as the attribute? And change the route name to something else like RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("FindACenterMap-post",

Comment: Yep, I tried both of those, still a 404. I added more details to the question.

Comment: Also, if I change the controller action and the route to be a GET instead of a POST, it works. Wonder why it doesn't like POST.

Comment: Moved to chat. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84243/room-for-chris-auer-and-chi-coder-007